# get userPackagerOpts.sourceExts is not iterable while runing the expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting the following error while runing the expo app.

```
   $ expo-cli start --tunnel
    [00:24:51] Starting project at C:\Users\DEMO\Desktop\worldsweets
    [00:24:51] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
    [00:24:59] userPackagerOpts.sourceExts is not iterable
    [00:24:59] TypeError: userPackagerOpts.sourceExts is not iterable
        at startReactNativeServerAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@57.9.12\src\Project.ts:1788:80)
        at Object.startAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@57.9.12\src\Project.ts:2407:5)
        at action (C:\Users\DEMO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:181:3)
        at C:\Users\DEMO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:354:16
        at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DEMO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:80:7)
```

Comment: Which expo-cli version do you use? Can you show your app.json?

Comment: "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "version": "2.1.0",

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is an old bug that has been reintroduced in expo-cli v3.21.2 or v3.21.3. I am using expo-cli v3.21.3 and ran into this issue too.

[This post](https://forums.expo.io/t/userpackageropts-sourceexts-is-not-iterable-expo-cli-3-21-3/38287/4) on the expo forum suggested adding `"sourceExts": ["js", "jsx", "svg", "svgx"]` to your app.json under packagerOpts and worked to get my project running again.

app.json

```
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": ["ttf"],
      "sourceExts": ["js", "jsx", "svg", "svgx"]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the `expo-cli` version to `3.17.10`.

This new version seems to fix this issue.

```
npm install expo-cli@3.17.10 --save
```

Related question: https://forums.expo.io/t/userpackageropts-sourceexts-is-not-iterable/35271/4

Comment: I am using `yarn`

Comment: Im experiencing same problem with latest expo cli and seems no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your expo-cli
Run this command

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Problem Solved